# Optimisiation Wire Square

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

A wire of length $L$ is to be cut into two pieces and each piece is to be formed into a square. Where should the wire be cut to maximize and minimize the area of the two squares? I'm struggling because it says maximize but my method proves it's a minimum only using 2nd derivative test.

My solution: let $x$ be length of one piece and $l-x$ be length of other piece. The area of the two squares $A$ will be $A$ $=$ $\frac{x^2}{16} + \frac{(l-x)^2}{16}$. Combining we have $A = \frac{2x^2+l^2-2lx}{16} = \frac{x^2}{8} + \frac{l^2}{16} - \frac{lx}{8}$

Differentiating with respect to $x$ I get $\frac{dA}{dx}$ $= \frac{x}{4} - \frac{l}{8}$. Hence $l=2x$ so $x=\frac{l}{2}$. Have I done this step correctly - $l$ differentiated with respect to $x$ is 0? This would imply that for a minimum (2nd derivative is positive) the wire must be cut exactly in half.

Intuitively I am thinking that for a maximum wouldn't this only be possible if the wire is cut into a square as small as possible with the other as large as possible. I am not too sure. So if I were in an exam I would say that for a maximum, the wire shouldn't be cut at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case of [constrained optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_optimization). $x$ has to be within $[0 \dots L]$.

You are right with your conclusion that $x=\frac{L}{2}$ is a minimum. But the maxima are the symmetric border cases $x=0$ and $x=L$.

**Example plot for $L=80$:**

[image]

For functions with constrained input one has to take the boundary into account.

Comment: So I am right in saying that the maximum occurs when the wire is cut at its endpoint so into two pieces of length $l$ and length $0$?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: Is the other poster contradicting your answer ? Are you sure I / you / we are right ?

Comment: Imagine $L=80$ cut into four wires á $20$. This would result in area sum $100$ which is far smaller than the maximum $400$ demonstrated above.

Comment: Alright cool, that’s what I thought. Thanks both of you :)

Answer (score 0):

The process of maximization is to be continued for *each* cut piece for *a second time*.

Let $y$ be cut part of each cutpiece length $l/2$. Then for the smaller rectangle

$$A_{~cut piece boundary}= y\cdot (\frac{l}{4} -y)$$

has a maximum at $y=\dfrac{l}{8}$ with negative second derivative.

Comment: Poster above said it's at the endpoints which I thought. What'd you think ?

Comment: As I understand, you wanted the manner in which the *two* cut wires should be bent again for *maximum* combined area.

Comment: I wanted where the wire should be cut to give two squares of maximum area combined (two squares in total only)

Comment: Yes, so first cut the full wire in half, then bend each half to a square.

Comment: What would the side lengths of the two squares be in that case ? $0.125l$? Isn’t that what I did but that gives a minimum. You said the second derivative is negative - how ?

Comment: Consider only the second part. What is the sign after twice differentiating $y\cdot (\frac{l}{4} -y)$?